# Logging level not applied

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

it seems that in python setting the logging level for loggers (including the root logger) is not applied, until you use one of the logging module's logging functions. Here's some code to show what I mean (I used python 3.7):

```py
import logging


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a test logger and set its logging level to DEBUG
    test_logger = logging.getLogger("test")
    test_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Log some debug messages
    # THESE ARE NOT PRINTED
    test_logger.debug("test debug 1")

    # Now use the logging module directly to log something
    logging.debug("whatever, you won't see this anyway")

    # Apparently the line above "fixed" the logging for the custom logger
    # and you should be able to see the message below
    test_logger.debug("test debug 2")
```

Output:

```
DEBUG:test:test debug 2
```

Maybe there's something I misunderstood about the configuration of the loggers, in that case I'd appreciate to know the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't (explicitly) call `logging.basicConfig`, so the handler isn't configured correctly.

`test_logger` initially has no handler, because you didn't add one and the root logger doesn't have one yet. So although the message is "logged", nothing defines what that actually means.

When you call `logging.debug`, `logging.basicConfig` is called for you, because the root logger has no handler. At this time, a `StreamHandler` is created, but the root logger remains at the default level of `INFO`, and so nothing is sent to the new handler.

Now when you call `test_logger.debug` again, it has the inherited `StreamHandler` to actually output the long message to standard error.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's it!. I didn't realize the fact about the handlers!